# git push gives fatal error via git-lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a site that uses git-lfs to push a few large binary files. It was working until I updated my OS to High Sierra (10.13.1).

My git version is 2.15.0

Env info for git-lfs

- git-lfs/1.1.1 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.5.3)

Error output is below.

```
unexpected fault address 0x43ae71333512
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x43ae71333512 pc=0x43ae71333512]

goroutine 53 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x502418, 0x5)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:527 +0x90 fp=0xc820038928 sp=0xc820038910
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:27 +0x2ba fp=0xc820038978 sp=0xc820038928
net/http.(*Transport).dial(0xc820091290, 0x5044a8, 0x3, 0xc820276320, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:499 +0x79 fp=0xc8200389c0 sp=0xc820038978
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0xc820091290, 0x0, 0xc82028e000, 0x5, 0xc820276320, 0xe, 0x5d0b08, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:596 +0x19a9 fp=0xc820038f00 sp=0xc8200389c0
net/http.(*Transport).getConn.func4(0xc820091290, 0x0, 0xc82028e000, 0x5, 0xc820276320, 0xe, 0xc82027a120)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:549 +0x66 fp=0xc820038f78 sp=0xc820038f00
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1721 +0x1 fp=0xc820038f80 sp=0xc820038f78
created by net/http.(*Transport).getConn
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:551 +0x265

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc8200fb2ac)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/sema.go:43 +0x26
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc8200fb2a0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/sync/waitgroup.go:126 +0xb4
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).Wait(0xc8200fb1e0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:101 +0x2b6
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.prePushRef(0xc8200fcb92, 0x28, 0xc8200fe3c0, 0x29)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/command_pre_push.go:129 +0x4c1
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.prePushCommand(0x75f9e0, 0xc82008ee60, 0x2, 0x2)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/command_pre_push.go:72 +0x433
github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/_nuts/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x75f9e0, 0xc82008eca0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/_nuts/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:477 +0x403
github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/_nuts/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x7610a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/_nuts/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:551 +0x46a
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.Run()
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/commands.go:88 +0x23
main.main()
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/git-lfs.go:34 +0x12e

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1721 +0x1

goroutine 19 [syscall]:
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x18
created by os/signal.init.1
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x37

goroutine 22 [select, locked to thread]:
runtime.gopark(0x5d1810, 0xc820026728, 0x503fe0, 0x6, 0x2d718, 0x2)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:185 +0x163
runtime.selectgoImpl(0xc820026728, 0x0, 0x18)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/select.go:392 +0xa64
runtime.selectgo(0xc820026728)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/select.go:212 +0x12
runtime.ensureSigM.func1()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/signal1_unix.go:227 +0x323
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1721 +0x1

goroutine 23 [chan receive]:
main.main.func1(0xc820096de0, 0xc820063910)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/git-lfs.go:22 +0x6d
created by main.main
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/git-lfs.go:32 +0x129

goroutine 31 [chan receive]:
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).errorCollector(0xc8200fb1e0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:256 +0x5b
created by github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).run
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:317 +0x3f

goroutine 33 [chan receive]:
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).transferWorker(0xc8200fb1e0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:270 +0x98
created by github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).run
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:322 +0x167

goroutine 34 [chan receive]:
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).transferWorker(0xc8200fb1e0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:270 +0x98
created by github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).run
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:322 +0x167

goroutine 35 [chan receive]:
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).transferWorker(0xc8200fb1e0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:270 +0x98
created by github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).run
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:322 +0x167

goroutine 37 [select]:
net/http.(*Transport).getConn(0xc820091290, 0xc820290000, 0x0, 0xc82028e000, 0x5, 0xc820276320, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:554 +0x663
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0xc820091290, 0xc820290000, 0xb3, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:228 +0x4ac
net/http.send(0xc820290000, 0xca4488, 0xc820091290, 0xc82028e870, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/client.go:220 +0x52c
net/http.(*Client).send(0xc8200ffd10, 0xc820290000, 0x45, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/client.go:143 +0x15a
net/http.(*Client).doFollowingRedirects(0xc8200ffd10, 0xc820290000, 0x5d1410, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/client.go:380 +0xbc0
net/http.(*Client).Do(0xc8200ffd10, 0xc820290000, 0x764460, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/net/http/client.go:178 +0x188
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*HttpClient).Do(0xc82006e330, 0xc820290000, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/http.go:65 +0x115
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.doHttpRequest(0xc820290000, 0xc8200e6570, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/client.go:493 +0x633
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.doApiRequestWithRedirects(0xc820290000, 0xc820049aa8, 0x0, 0x4, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/client.go:537 +0xb0
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.doAPIRequest(0xc820290000, 0x504701, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/client.go:479 +0x8e
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.doApiBatchRequest(0xc820290000, 0x13, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/client.go:443 +0x13a
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.Batch(0xc820276030, 0x2, 0x2, 0x504788, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/client.go:235 +0x627
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).batchApiRoutine(0xc8200fb1e0)
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:205 +0x456
created by github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*TransferQueue).run
    /private/tmp/git-lfs20160205-83071-1xrm8js/git-lfs-1.1.1/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/transfer_queue.go:328 +0x2b7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a very similar error message, and **I fixed the issue by updating my git-lfs version**. Since you seem to be using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) as well, these terminal commands will hopefully do the trick for you, too:

```
# Update Homebrew:
brew update

# Upgrade the git-lfs package
brew upgrade git-lfs

# Update global git config
git lfs install
```

At this point, `git lfs version` reported "*git-lfs/2.3.4 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.9.1)*” and then my `git push` command ran successfully again.

Comment: Commits finally pushed after 6 weeks! Thanks!!